# Binding the same event to SVG g element and it's child

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Using D3, I'm trying to bind a drag event to a 'g', group element, and a separate drag event to a child of this group. This seems to be causing issues as only group's drag event fires.

I've read through the specs a bit but don't see anything relating to this. Here's the code:

```
var group = that.vis.append('g')
            .classed('dragger', true)
            .attr('transform', 'translate(100, 0)')
            .call(drag.on( 'drag', function() {...} )),

    box = group.append('rect')
            .attr('width', that.width * options.width)
            .attr('height', that.height)
            .classed('box', true);

var left = group.append('rect')
                .attr('width', 4).attr('x', 0)
                .attr('height', that.height)
                .classed('drag-extend right', true)
                .call(drag2.on('drag', function(){...}));
```

'that.vis' refers to the d3 selection containing the svg element. The d3 drag behaviors were created like so:

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
                    .origin(function() {
                      var string = d3.select(this).attr('transform'),
                            //string = string.replace(/translate\(/, '');
                            array = string.match( /translate\((\d+), (\d+)\)/ );

                      return {
                        x : parseInt(array[1]),
                        y : parseInt(array[2])
                      }
                    }),

    drag2 = d3.behavior.drag()
                  .origin(function() {
                      return {
                         x : d3.select(this).attr('x'),
                         y : 0
                      };
                   });
```

I need the elements to be grouped in order to move the whole group. My only thought is that when you attach an event handler to a SVG group it attaches that handler to all elements inside it? I'd like to be able to just stop propagation on the second element's drag handler so it doesn't bubble up to the 'g' parent however the second event doesn't seem to be attached at all.

Kind of at loss here, any help would be much appreciated...

**UPDATE**
So I was able to get this working but not in a way that I would of expected and I'm still interested in what exactly is going on here:

```
drag2 = d3.behavior.drag()
                  .origin(function() {
                      return {
                         x : d3.select(this).attr('x'),
                         y : 0
                      };
                   }).on( 'drag', shapeBox );

var left = group.append('rect')
                .attr('width', 4).attr('x', 0)
                .attr('height', that.height)
                .classed('drag-extend right', true)

                .call(drag2.on('dragstart', function(){...}));


function shapeBox() { ... }
```

For some reason adding the 'dragstart' handler somehow got the drag handler attached directly to the behavior to fire. This is strange because in looking at the d3 docs and from my knowledge of the DOM (which may be somewhat limited), I should have just been able to pass the 'drag2' variable to call.

Not sure what binding the extra listener did but somehow that got the drag to work.

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't actually make sense. An SVG `<g>` element doesn't take up any space on the page. It's not something that a user could drag. The `<g>` element isn't like an HTML `<div>` in that way; it's just a "notational" convenience to refer to all of the child elements at once. Properties and attributes of `<g>` elements just flow through to their children. So dragging a `<g>` and dragging its child are exactly the same thing.

Comment: So how would you propose to move a group of SVG elements at once? I'm not saying that you are wrong, but I am able to translate the g element and I do have what I was trying to accomplish working with the hack.

Comment: I do appreciate the response btw...

Comment: When you translate a group, like all attributes, the translation flows through to the children. So you're actually translating all of the children separately. The group is (more or less) just a convenient shorthand.